# How to write (byte) 0xFF in VB.NET

Tags: java, vb.net, porting

I have a little project that needs to create a static array of bytes.

I got Java code to create a fixed array of bytes in Java like the code below.

```
private static final byte[][] P = new byte[][] {

    // p0
    {
        (byte) 0xA9, (byte) 0x67, (byte) 0xB3, (byte) 0xE8,
        (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0xFD, (byte) 0xA3, (byte) 0x76
    },

    // p1
    {
        (byte) 0x75, (byte) 0xF3, (byte) 0xC6, (byte) 0xF4,
        (byte) 0xDB, (byte) 0x7B, (byte) 0xFB, (byte) 0xC8}
    }
```

How can I write it in VB.NET?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
Dim P(,) As Byte = New Byte(,) { _
    { &HA9, &H67, ... }, _
    { &H75, &HF3, ... }, _
    ... _
}
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that VB.NET has no explicit way to write a byte literal.  The best you can do is to use a sufficiently small integer literal, as you have shown and trust that it will convert to a byte properly.  I suppose if you wanted to be explicit, you could say `CByte(&HA9)`, but it's not necessary.

Comment: That's true - neither does Java, hence the `(byte)` cast. Fortunately, The VB compiler, in this context, is aware of the range limitation, and will happily carp if one of the constants is too large to fit into a `Byte`.

Answer (score 2):

The `byte` type in Java is a signed type, whereas the `Byte` type in VB.NET is unsigned.  For VB you need to use the `SByte` type.  Also, your question shows an array of arrays, not a 2-dimensional array, so the closest equivalent in VB.NET would be:

```
Private Shared ReadOnly P()() As SByte = _ 
    { _
    New SByte() { CSByte(&HA9), CSByte(&H67), CSByte(&HB3), CSByte(&HE8), CSByte(&H4), CSByte(&HFD), CSByte(&HA3), CSByte(&H76) }, _
    New SByte() { CSByte(&H75), CSByte(&HF3), CSByte(&HC6), CSByte(&HF4), CSByte(&HDB), CSByte(&H7B), CSByte(&HFB), CSByte(&HC8) } _
    }
```